# Does Ofelia imagine drawing doors in Pan's Labyrinth?

Tags: pans-labyrinth

Ofelia is drawing at least three doors during [*Pan's Labyrinth*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0457430/). The last one is her way of escaping from her locked room.

The first two doors could be imagined, but the last one? Escape from a locked room?

Is this a proof that Ofelia is not dreaming or imagining things?

Comment: Could you be a little more specific as to what you are asking? The bold sub-headings are distracting and seem to only break the flow of whatever your specific question may be. (No downvote or VTC, just unclear.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The last door does give the impression that what Ofelia experiences is, at least partly, real and not pure imagination. Also, director Guillermo Del Toro has stated the following in an [interview](http://twitchfilm.com/2006/12/pans-labyrinthinterview-with-guillermo-del-toro.html#ixzz36FdF4a9M):

> Now objectively, the way I structured it, there are three clues in the movie that tell you where I stand. I stand in that it's real. The most important clues are the flower at the end, and the fact that there's no way other than the chalk door to get from the attic to the Captain's office.